# I accidentally block request URL in safari developer tools. How to unblock?

Tags: safari

This is what happens when I open developer tools accessing the blocked URL:

[image]

I can't right-click -> unblock on the URL in the network tab because it's not listed there.

How to unblock it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem and finally find a solution,
After blocking request it is dropping to the tab Sources and under section Local Override, find the request you have blocked and simply tick the checkbox and that's it